# How to ignore/delete undefined characters on string decoded

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding, undefined, decode

I'm reading a bus with bytes-like sequence of characters and i need to decode it in a string, but when I use decode method the output show undefined characters and i need to delete/ignore them.
Thanks all for help

I have already tried to use the method decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'), or with encoding='ascii', but I get same result.

```
x = ser.read_until(b'\x03', None) 

string = x.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
```

This is the actual result: xx423711B552000083x  (x = undefined character)

And I expected to have: 423711B552000083

Comment: Is not what do you have? BTW you should provide a working example. So  could you write x as x= b'\xc0\xc1\x35\x75\x64" .. etc?  SO we can also understand better what problem do you have. 'ignore' should really ignore. I think the error is in other places.

Comment: If the sender is sending bytes for text, which character encoding is it using? If not, why do you want to process non-text as text?